# Import data from cell with html format

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

How i can do to put inside a var a custom text from a cell in google sheets, to send via e-mail after that in a html table, but, with the format of the text.

Ex.:
Cell in Google Sheets:

"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Ut tenetur aspernatur et nostrum earum sit quia quibusdam et doloribus tempore sed commodi laudantium est internos perferendis ea debitis nemo. Est quae iure non sequi Quis ea architecto iure est laudantium omnis id temporibus quae et voluptatem maxime sit voluptatibus mollitia. Et eius vitae a rerum sed voluptas Quis. In enim animi At vero earum non quia voluptate et magnam distinctio aut laudantium exercitationem a fuga inventore in omnis commodi.

Ut aperiam vero id culpa molestias sed dolorum sint est dolores laudantium ut ullam excepturi? Sit sint inventore hic consequatur corporis qui laudantium dolor quo ipsa minus non aliquid vero est laboriosam nobis! Qui internos odit 33 sequi maiores eos perferendis enim ut adipisci unde? Sed delectus iste 33 aperiam pariatur qui labore animi ut nisi quis et amet voluptatem qui sint officiis."

but when i try put in a var this break line desapear.

Comment: About `but when i try put in a var this break line desapear.`, I thought that in your question, when you provide your current script and explain the current issue of your script, it will help users think of the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming data is in range A1, try to replace `\n` by `<br>` and use htmlbody instead of body

```
function test() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sh = ss.getActiveSheet()
  MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message, {
    htmlBody: sh.getRange('A1').getValue().replace(/\n/g, '<br>'),
    cc: 'internal1@email.com',
    bcc: 'internal2@email.com'
  });
};
```

Comment: Yeah, replace works.
I used this to replace all \n to <br/> ===> .replace(/(\r\n|\r|\n)/g,"<br/>");